# How do I get a slideshow only on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, slideshow

I'm wondering how I can get a slideshow to only view on mobile. I need 3 different sections next to each other on my webpage and when width turns below 640px I need it to turn into a slideshow.
I found a webpage that has this integrated:

Normal page:
[Normal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvPny.png)

Mobile page:
[Mobile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utNZa.png)

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the script I'm using:

```html
<script>
      
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);
        
        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }
        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }
        
        function showSlides(n) {
          var i;
          var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
          if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
          if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length} 
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";  
          }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
          dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Use media queries to show hide the slider component as per the screen size

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #slider_component {
    display: block;
  }
}
#slider_component {
    display: none;
  }
```

**Option 2**

If you are using any of the css frameworks like bootstrap or foundation, you can attach hooks to show/hide elements on the page as per the screen size. Check out their docs [here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/visibility.html).

Comment: When I do this. On the normal page I'm only able to see one of the 3 slider components.

Comment: Is it possible to only toggle the script when max width of a page is below a certain lvl?

Comment: Yes, you can do this javascript as well. You can toggle your slider based on the desired screen size by checking screen.height and screen.width

Answer (score 0):

you have to add id if not already existe to your tag, exemple id="slider" and add this code to your style:

```
#slider {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #slider {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

good luck.

Comment: When I do this. On the normal page I'm only able to see one of the 3 slider components.

Comment: can you add a screenshot ?